# Vue data table sort doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I have this `v-data-table`:

```
  <v-data-table :headers="walletInHeaders" :items="filteredByQuantityIncome" class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:items="props">
      <td class="pa-1 text-xs-center">
        <v-btn @click="loginAsClient(props.item.email)" color="blue">Login as client</v-btn>
        {{ props.item.email }}
      </td>
      <td class="pa-1 text-xs-center">{{ props.item.currency }}</td>
      <td class="pa-1 text-xs-center">{{ props.item.quantity }}</td>
      <td class="pa-1 text-xs-center">{{ props.item.totalIncomeAmount.toFixed(8) }}</td>
      <td class="pa-1 text-xs-center" style="white-space: pre-line">{{ props.item.types }}</td>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

And headers:

```
  walletInHeaders: [
    {text: 'Email (click on email to log in as client)', value: 'email', align: 'center', class: 'px-0', sortable: false},
    {text: 'Currency', value: 'curr', align: 'center', class: 'px-0', sortable: false},
    {text: 'Quantity', value: 'quan', align: 'center', class: 'px-0'},
    {text: 'Total income amount', value: 'totalIncomeAmount', align: 'center', class: 'px-0', sortable: false},
    {text: 'Payment methods', value: 'mostPopularPaymentMethod', align: 'center', class: 'px-0', sortable: false},
  ],
```

As you can see, there is a fiend `quantity` (it's integer in code), and I want to make table sort using this column. By default it doesn't work correctly at all. Not `quantity` field, not others.

I wrote, that this is integer column in code. Also, I was trying to use `sortable: false` and on other columns `:sort-by="['quan]" :sort-desc="true"` on table, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I should pay attention to `value` property in headers. As you can see, in `HTML` I have, for example, `props.item.currency`, but in headers     `{text: 'Currency', value: 'curr', align: 'center', class: 'px-0', sortable: false}`. So, I just change `curr` value to `currency`, just like object's properties name. I did it for every property and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`sort-by` and `sort-order` fields are String and Boolean respectively. They are Arrays only if `multi-sort` is true.

If multi-sort is disabled: Try `sort-by="quan"` instead of `:sort-by="['quan']"`.

If multi-sort is enabled: Try `:sort-desc=[true]` instead of `:sort-desc="true"`.